# Network issue with the accessing computers

Tags: networking

My client has two machines. Ex A and B.

When I tried accessing B from A remotely it works. But when I tried accessing A from B remotely its not working. I could not ping A. It was working all these days. Suddenly i am having this issue.

Can anyone help me solving this issue.

Thanks and Regards,
Pavan

Comment: Your question is way too vague. You must explain what you want to access remotely, SSH? Desktop? And describe your network setup.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to check for the firewall . Maybe those settings were changed .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall issue but it is hard to tell without more information.

**Assumptions/Environment**:

-You can ping in one direction but not the other

-Switching/Routing between hosts works since you are able to establish some type of connection between the two, albeit in only one direction

-You used to be able to ping in both directions (inbound/outbound ping enabled on both hosts and firewall/routers allow such traffic in both directions)

**Tests you should perform**:

-traceroute or tracert on host A to host B's IP

-traceroute or tracert on host B to host A's IP
Assuming ping used to work in both directions and now it doesn't, you should see 100% packet loss at the device which is causing your network issue.  Contact the network admin or relevant person to check the logs on the device in questions, and resolve the issue.

Perhaps bi-directional ping never worked to begin with or is blocked in your environment.  Or perhaps you were unable to ping in both directions before but resolved pinging using the previous suggestion but you still can't connect to the remote host using your remote access software.

-telnet to the remote host using the port of the remote access software you are using to see if the port is open.  If the port is not open, then check that the service that enables your remote access protocol is running and that the port is open.  You can list the listening ports using the netstat command.  To check for running services, refer to your relevant OS documentation.

---

For a more specific answer or more specific commands you will need to provide a more detailed question such as "I am using Windows and can RDP between two hosts in one direction but not the opposite direction from the same LAN" or "I am using linux and can ssh between two hosts in one direction but not the opposite direction between the DMZ and internal network"